# QGLWidget update(rect) always paints the entire rect

Tags: ios, macos, performance, qt, qt5

I have a simple painting app using a `QGLWidget` that I am calling `update(rect)` on, passing in a rect that is much smaller than the rect of the `QGLWidget`. I use a `QImage` to draw into, and then in the `paintEvent`, I draw a portion of that to the `QGLWidget`. When I put a break point on the `paintEvent` method, and call `event->rect()` or `event->region().rects()`, it returns the entire rect of the `QGLWidget`. I would have expected it to return only the rect that was passed to the update method.

As a consequence, drawing on my iPhone is horribly laggy.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/beyyHCPw

If you scroll to the bottom of the pastebin, you will see my logging code where I am logging which rect I draw (draw rect) to and then later which rect comes back in the paint event (update rect).

Comment: Have you checked that your normalized rect's coordinates are proper?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I had a qDebug in there and was looking at my rect coordinates and they looked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is expected if QGLWidget is using double buffering and that you're asked to draw in a different buffer each time.

Dirty rects are a concept not normally used that way with GL as far as I know.

The performance problem with your code might also be that you're uploading the content of your 1024x1536 QImage to graphics memory each time you draw it after it changed in main memory. Drawing to an intermediate Q(Open)GLFramebufferObject could be an improvement (though fast blitting using GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit might not be supported on the iPhone).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try a QGLFramebuffer object. How do I get the frame buffer into the QGLWidget?

Comment: Use the QOpenGL* classes instead of QGL* if you can (in 5.4), the latter are being deprecated. You can use QOpenGLFramebufferObject::​blitFramebuffer if hasOpenGLFramebufferBlit is true. Else it gets more complicated, you have to get the texture id from QOpenGLFramebufferObject::texture, and draw it using raw GL code on the QOpenGLWidget, wrapped in QPainter::​beginNativePainting. It can get messy quite fast, so make sure that you tried using a non-GL QWidget or using a QML Canvas item first, they should give you good performances in non-extreme scenarios too.

Comment: What's the easiest way to draw a GOpenGLFramebufferObject to a QOpenGLWidget? QOpenGLWidget doesn't have a drawTexture method.

Comment: To clarify a bit: QOpenGLFramebufferObject::​blitFramebuffer with target=0, but again only if hasOpenGLFramebufferBlit is true (which means that your GL drivers supports GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit).